# Likert package - add a separate N/A column

Tags: bar-chart, survey, likert, ordinal-classification

I would like to make a diverging bar graph of likert responses and include a separate bar for N/A responses (like in the image)
[diverging bar chart with NA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3qLS.png)

I have pre-summarised data (shown in table), which I have plotted without the NA column so far:
[summary data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSScl.png)

Using the following code:
plot(likert(summary=q25),plot.percent.neutral=FALSE,legend.position='right')